# $t^2$ can't be a solution to the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that $y(t)=t^2$ will never be a solution to such a differential equation:
$$y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0$$
where $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are continuous.

I tried to compute that i.e. $$2+p(t)*2t+q(t)t^2=0$$
And then: $\Delta=4p^2-8q$. But I don't know if it helps me even a little bit. How should I do this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting $t=0$ ............

Comment: So the proof will be completed if I just say that if $t^2$ would be a solution then it wouldn't be ok for $t=0$? So $t^2$ can't be a solution?

Comment: Basically. Get convinced about it by writing the *ab absurdum* proof in full $\exists, \forall$ verbiage

Comment: Of course! 

Should it look like that (more less):
If $t^2$ would be a solution then $(\exists p,q \in C )(\forall t\in \mathbb{R})(2+p(t)*2t+t^2=0)$. But I can find such a $t(=0)$, that it's not true. Hence contradiction.

Comment: Almost ok. I assume you're not native English speaking (neither am I) so it's probably clearer in your mother tongue. But as I understand the problem, $p,q$ are given parameters of your DE, so they should come first in your sentence.

Comment: $p,q$ are continuous functions. It should be $(\exists p(t),q(t) \in C )$

Comment: Still, "parameters" of the problem (ie not the unknown)

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you :)